# transform property value of object using reduce?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const ori = {
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AS": "American Samoa"
}
```

How do I concate above array of object into

```
{
    "AL": "+ Alabama",
    "AK": "+ Alaska",
    "AS": "+ American Samoa"
}
```

using reduce?

I tried

```
const r = Object.entries(ori).reduce((accum, [key, value], i) => {
    console.log(key)
    accum = {[key]: `+ ${value}`}

    return accum
},{})
console.log(r)
```

I only got the last iteration value.

Comment: reduce is for arrays, you'd have to convert it first. also reduce is for many->one, and you want many->many, which is a map().

Comment: The first piece of code is only an object, not an array of objects.

Comment: @dandavis updated my question

Comment: The reason your attempt doesn't work is because you assign the accumulator to an entirely new object each iteration. What you want to do is add new properties to the existing accumulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `...` operator to combine the current value of `accum` with the next entry:

```js
const ori = {
    "AL": "Alabama",
    "AK": "Alaska",
    "AS": "American Samoa"
}

const r = Object.entries(ori).reduce((accum, [key, value]) => {
    console.log(key)
    return {...accum, [key]: `+ ${value}`};
},{})
console.log(r)
```

Comment: Seems kinda odd to recreate the accumulator each iteration when you could just use `return accum[key] = '+ ' + value, accum`

Comment: @Phil Sure, you could, but part of the idea of functional programming (such as `reduce`) is avoiding mutability. `accum[key] =` would mutate the accumulator object. If the number of items is a known commodity and it's small, then the approach above shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: Since the accumulator is created new specifically for the reduce operation, I don't think I've ever seen an issue in mutating it

Comment: @Phil No, there's no issue in mutating it. It's simply a matter of whether you want to consistently adhere to immutability or not.

Comment: @Melissa94:  [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 1):

> transform property value of an object

An alternative for using `reduce`

Try this:

```js
const obj = {
  "AL": "Alabama",
  "AK": "Alaska",
  "AS": "American Samoa"
}
let clone = {}
for (var propt in obj) {
  clone[propt] = `+ ${obj[propt]}`
}
console.log(clone )
```